# Are torsion submodules not unique?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, definition

[image]

This was a statement as part a lemma in my book (Goodman) on page 388. I found this very ambiguous because

1. What exactly is $A$ in relation to $M$? Do they mean $A = Tor(M) \cap S$ where $S$ is some submodule of $M$?
2. What exactly is **a** torsion submodule? I thought there is only **the** torsion submodule $Tor(M).$
3. This theorem 8.5.2 is the Structure Theorem (existence) where $M = R^k \oplus_{i = 1}^s R/(a_i)$ with $a_i |a_{i+1}$.

How do we know $\oplus_{i = 1}^s R/(a_i)$ is a torsion submodule?

Comment: So they meant for a submodule $S \subset M$, $A = \Tor(S)$?

Comment: Please replace the image of text by actual text to make it accessible for search engines and users with screen readers.

Comment: "A" torsion submodule is a submodule that is torsion (that is, $A$ is not assumed to be the full torsion submodule, but the conclusion of the lemma is that in fact it must be).

Answer (score 2):

Let $R$ be a unital commutative ring, and $M$ an $R$-module. Recall:

- An element $m \in M$ is a *torsion element* if $rm = 0$ for some regular (non zero-divisor) $r \in R$.
- Let $\operatorname{Tor}(M) \subseteq M$ be the set of all torsion elements, then $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule.
- $M$ itself is called a *torsion module* if $M = \operatorname{Tor}(M)$. In other words, a torsion module is a module consisting only of torsion elements.
- $M$ is called *torsion-free* if $\operatorname{Tor}(M) = \{0\}$.

If $R$ is a PID, then we can replace the word "regular" with "nonzero". The theorem is trying to say that in any random direct sum decomposition $M = A \oplus B$ where $A$ happens to be torsion and $B$ happens to be free, then in fact $A$ is equal to *the* torsion submodule $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$.

As for how to see that $\bigoplus_{i} R / (a_i)$ is a torsion module, is it clear to see that each $R / (a_i)$ is a torsion module? Once you see that, consider the proof of the fact that $\operatorname{Tor}(M)$ is a submodule: there should be a similar looking trick.

Comment: So $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily internal decompositions? And $A$ could be unrelated to $M$ and it could be that $A = Tor(N)$ for some module $N$ unrelated to $M$?

Comment: $R/(a_i)$ is torsion because for any coset $r + (a_i)$, I can apply $a_i$ to it to turn $a_i(r + (a_i))= a_i r + (a_i)$ and clearly $a_i r \in (a_i)$. Since $r$ is chosen arbitrary from the representatives, $R/(a_i)$ is torsion.

Comment: @Hawk If $M$ appears first, then I read $M = A \oplus B$ as an internal direct sum, i.e. both $A$ and $B$ are submodules of $M$ which happen to satisfy $A + B = M$ and $A \cap B = \{0\}$. On the other hand if it read $M \cong A \oplus B$, then I would assume that $A \oplus B$ was some external direct sum, and there existed an isomorphism $\varphi \colon M \to A \oplus B$. (Keep in mind that in this case, $\varphi^{-1}(A)$ and $\varphi^{-1}(B)$ form an internal direct sum of $M$).

Comment: But in this case, it is an external sum right? Also apparently the author relaxed the condition of $R$ from PID to just an integral domain.

Comment: @Hawk I think that you can read it either as an external or internal direct sum and the result doesn't change

Comment: Are the proofs different? All the ones I have found involves exact sequences (and projective modules), which this book talks neither of. So I am assuming a more elementary technique proof exists.

Comment: In part (b) how do they know the leftover $B$ must be isomorphic to the quotient part (I know quotient is torsion free, but how do they know this is the right module to be isomorphic to)?

Answer (score 1):

They're being a bit vague about equality vs isomorphism (which is customary once one is more familiar with things) so here's a more precise way of saying what they mean:

First we define an $R$-module to be **torsion** if for all $m\in M$ there is some nonzero $r\in R$ with $rm=0$. The claim then is that if there is any isomorphism $\phi:M\to A\oplus B$ where $A$ is a torsion $R$-module and $B$ is free, then the image of $M_{\mathrm{tor}}$ under $\phi$ is exactly equal to $A\oplus\{0\}$.

So you see they are not requiring that $A$ literally be a submodule of $M$ but rather isomorphic to one.

A torsion submodule of $M$ is a submodule which happens to be a torsion module. **The** torsion submodule of $M$ is the submodule $M_{\mathrm{tor}}:=\{m\in M\mid\text{there exists $r\in R\smallsetminus\{0\}$ with $rm=0$}\}$. Alternatively it is the **largest** torsion submodule of $M$, and it is unique in this sense.

Comment: So a torsion submodule of $M$ has to be a submodule of $TorM.$ But in this case $A$ could be a submodule of another different module with a different structure (but still over the PID $R$ or a different PID $R$ for that matter)

Comment: Yes, except all modules we are considering should be over the same PID $R$ that we started with

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $\phi(Tor M) = A$? That seems like the result.

Comment: On one hand, if $x\in A$ then because $A$ is torsion you know that $x$ is a torsion element, and from this you can conclude that $\phi^{-1}(x)$ is a torsion element of $M$, but then $x=\phi(\phi^{-1}(x))\in \phi(M_{\mathrm{tor}})$.

Comment: on the other hand if $m\in M_{\mathrm{tor}}$ then $\phi(m)$ is a torsion of element of $A\oplus B$, but if we write $\phi(m)=(a,b)$ for some $a\in A$ and $b\in B$ then because $b$ is free and $\phi(m)$ is torsion you can conclude that $b=0$. There are some details left out but I hope this gives you enough to fill in the gaps.

Comment: So if $m\in \TorM$, there exists a non zero $r$ such that $rm = 0 \implies (0,0) = \phi(0) = \phi(rm) = r\phi(m) = r(a,b) = (ra,rb).$ That $ra = 0$ is fine because $A$ is a torsion submodule. But $rb = 0$ on a free module implies that if $(x_\beta)$ is a basis, then $0= rb = r\sum x_\beta \implies$ the basis elements are $0$?

Comment: Actually the shorter answer is that free modules are torsion free, hence $b=0$. But this uses (c)....